# How to check debug log

Tags: debug

I guess this is a simple task , but since I haven't worked must on coding would need some help on how to check debug log .
Currently my ask is to see if a method is being called and a map is being formed.
What kind of syntax should I look in the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user the `Developer console` to debug and log some informations : https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_debugging_system_log_console.htm

You can add somme logs in your code.

-If you want to log in `APEX` classes, add in your class :

```
system.debug('what you want to log here');
```

In the log tab in the Developer console, double click on the line concerned and check the debug checkbox to see your log line.

-If you want to log in Javascript, add in your Javascript file :

```
console.log('what you want to log here');
```

You need to use a browser debugger like Firebug for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very generic question which has no direct ansnwer. Hope below link help...Let me know if I could help to understand something in below link.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_debugging_debug_log.htm